# Can't access file in home directory from PHP on a EC2 server

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, home-directory

I am wondering why this returns an empty string:

```
$settings = file_get_contents('/home/ec2-user/settings.json');
```

but this works:

```
$settings = file_get_contents('/var/www/settings.json');
```

I can't seem to be able to access my json file from the home directory.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Apache runs under the `www` user, which has its home folder set to `/var/www`. And since PHP scripts are run in Apache's context, they also inherit it's user. Thus, your script cannot access files from other users home folder.

If you'd run the code in question via CLI (you being logged via `ssh`), you'd be able to access the contents of `/home/ec2-user/settings.json` as the script would run in the context of your user.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the web server runs as its own user. That user does not have a home directory (in /home) and is not allowed to access a home directory of any other users.

If `display_errors` is turned on, you should see a warning using `file_get_contents` to access a file that you have no permission to access.